# Instance culling using geometry shaders

Tags: frustum-culling

I'm developing my own game and for that I want to implement frustum culling, to archive an performance optimization. I found a description on the internet ([enter link description here](http://rastergrid.com/blog/2010/02/instance-culling-using-geometry-shaders/)) and this one looked really good - but I didn't understood it...
Maybe you can read through it and explain me the concept of this technique. Firstly I don't know the exact concept and secondly I don't know, how I could implement this.

Maybe you can explain it to me and then give me an Idea, how to implement this..

Second Question:
Is this a good technique? (Currently I have implemented frustum culling with boundingspheres, but the technique presented in the blog seems to be even better..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part 1: Process explanation**

We prepare information for each object / instance to be rendered: position + extents i.e. how far from its point position, the object extends in X,Y,Z - also known as an axis-aligned bounding box.

We pass that information to the vertex shader. The vertex shader tests each position + extents against the view frustum, geometrically, to see if objects are outside, inside, or partly inside the frustum; in the last two cases they should be rendered (see next step). We have a buffer of boolean flags, one for each instance, in which we set the flag to true if instance is (partly) within the frustum. How does the vertex shader do this? By transforming each of the 8 corner points of the axis aligned bounding box, into view space, then using a trick with `w` (the 4th component of your transformed 4D vector) to see whether or not it falls within the frustum. See `cull.vs` in the archive at your link.

Now we pass this buffer of flags to the geometry shader. Based on whether the 
flag has been set or not, we either emit geometry or do not so. Thats pretty simple; if an instance is not visible, we emit no geometry for it, meaning the GPU has less work to do. See `cull.gs` in the archive at your link.

**Part 2: Is it good?**

It depends very much on circumstances. You will have to pass a lot of instance information down the system bus from CPU to GPU, which for bus-limited systems (older mobiles?) may be an issue. Whereas if you do the culling on the CPU side, you will never have to pass that information as you will only pass those instances which your CPU has determined are necessary, to the GPU. Having said that, it is commonly a good pattern at least on desktops and powerful consoles to shift as much work off to the GPU as possible since CPU time is best used for game / engine logic. The same may not hold true on mobile; you'd have to profile on your target systems to be sure; these are just hints.

Comment: Wow, thank you very very much. This is excactly what I needed. Thanks.

I'm late but it still helps me! :)